# What should be the off-topic list of questions on the FAQ page?

Tags: discussion, faq

We can edit the faq page to clarify what is **off** topic.

See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq (among others) for an example.

Answer below with the bulleted list of what is **off**-topic and we'll see if we can help define at a high level what is **off** topic for inclusion in the faq.

---

Update:  I made the initial changes to the [FAQ page](https://money.stackexchange.com/faq) based on the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

- Questions about corporate or government finance
- Academic questions about economics or questions about economics that have no bearing on personal finance
- Argumentative questions about personal finance or government policy
- Questions that reveal logins to specific sites

Marked CW to make editing easier.

Comment: Is "the impact of government policy on personal finance" off topic?

Comment: In my opinion, I'd take off the logins line.  I think that is best covered through links to the meta question.

Comment: @Alex - argumentative ones should be, but I think neutral ones are on-topic (I thought I saw that here on meta).  Does that make sense?

Comment: what about: "Argumentative questions about personal finance or government policy."

Comment: @Alex - that sounds like a better way to phrase it.